# The Yogi that Never Eats, is it true?

Tags: physiology

A few years ago a yogi from India made the headlines claiming that he hadn't eaten for over 7 decades. It was said that he was under observation for 2 weeks in a hospital and allegedly was never seen ingesting any food or water, or going to the toilet. It was also reported that he had only limited contact with water while gargling and bathing.

Is there any documented scientific evidence that this yogi's claim is true? or has the claim been disproved?

A couple of sources for the story:

http://bodyodd.nbcnews.com/_news/2010/05/10/4380027-70-years-without-eating-starving-yogi-says-its-true?lite

http://www.thenational.ae/news/world/south-asia/holy-man-who-never-eats-baffles-scientists-in-india

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. The linked question seems broader than this one, although the answer does mention the above yogi. I'm not sure if it could easily be found if you are looking for information about this particular yogi though. At least I didn't turn up when I searched.